# Post form-data with remote url instead of local file

Tags: python, http, file-upload, python-requests

Scenario: Website x has a form in which a file can be uploaded from your local machine.

Question: Is it possible to pass in a remote url (e.g. `http://blah.whatever/file.ext`) instead of a local file, thus causing the remote server to download the file found at `http://blah.whatever/file.ext` instead of having to download the file to my local machine and then upload it?

I'm most familiar with Python. So, if this is possible through something like the `requests` module, that would be fantastic.